# Find and get specific word by punctuation, but then remove punctuation from result

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I tried everything to come up with a solution on my own to this problem, but I’m stumped and I could use some help. Any feedback you guys could give me would be great.

I have a dataset that pretty much follows the below sentence structure in each cell:

`Twelve little pigs rolled down the hill at Huckleberry, Farms: Citizen from Huckleberry`

I am trying to come up with an Excel formula that would capture the word “Huckleberry” by itself in a separate cell from where the data is populated (Cell `B2` In Example).

The structure for “Huckleberry” always has “,” attached to it and always precedes the following word that has a colon (:) attached to it so it basically follows the format of:

Huckleberry, Farms:
Bluefield, Meadows:
Buttercream, Valley:

I got pretty close to what I need using the formula:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",REPT(" ",99)),MAX(1,FIND(",",SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",REPT(" ",99)))-50),99))
```

But it retains the comma which gives me “Huckleberry,” when what I want is “Huckleberry”.

I would prefer an option, if at all possible, that uses the “:” from “Farms:” as a start point, working from right to left to find the “,” in “Huckleberry,” as sometimes there are commas that come before the initial comma found in “Huckleberry,”. But at this point any formula solution to this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: FYI I've updated my answer with a simpler formula and an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a plain vanilla normal formula that will work in any version of Excel:

```dart
=MID(B2,FIND("§",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2,FIND(":",B2))," ","§",LEN(LEFT(B2,FIND(":",B2)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2,FIND(":",B2))," ",""))-1))+1,FIND(",",B2,FIND("§",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2,FIND(":",B2))," ","§",LEN(LEFT(B2,FIND(":",B2)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2,FIND(":",B2))," ",""))-1)))-FIND("§",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2,FIND(":",B2))," ","§",LEN(LEFT(B2,FIND(":",B2)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2,FIND(":",B2))," ",""))-1))-1)
```

It will correctly return the word before the *first* colon if that word is followed by a comma, irrespective of how many other colons with a word-comma pair before them are in the data string.

The flaw with this formula is that if the word before the word before the first colon is *not* followed by a comma, it will return an error.

**Explanation:**

This formula is easier to understand if you use four helper cells:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

The formulas in the cells are:

`B3`:

```dart
=LEFT(B2,FIND(":",B2))
```

`B4`:

```dart
=LEN(B3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B3," ",""))
```

`B5`:

```dart
=SUBSTITUTE(B3," ","§",B4-1)
```

`B6`:

```dart
=FIND("§",B5)
```

`B7`:

```dart
=MID(B2,B6+1,FIND(",",B2,B6)-B6-1)
```

The full solution is simply the result of plugging in the the formulas for `B3`, `B4`, `B5`,and `B6` into `B7`.

**Notes:**

Actually keeping the four helper cells, rather than rolling the formulas into one, would make the formula much easier to maintain.

Even better still would be to keep the four helper cell formula in a "developer" worksheet, to make modifications easier, and use the rolled up formula in the production worksheet.

Comment: Thank You! This did in fact solve what I was looking for and I greatly appreciate the explanation of your formula breakdown. I hope to use this to go back and triage a few other formulas I have to see if I can make more sense of them now based on what you broke out here, but I still got a ways to go to get to something like you put together. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ExcelFunctionHelp You're welcome. You've inspired me to modify my answer to include an extra helper cell thus making the explanation even clearer. I've also added an extra tip at the end. btw, if you *really* appreciated my help, once you reach 15+ reputation don't forget to come back and upvote my answer as well ;-)

Answer (score 2):

this array formula will return the word with a comma before the word with a colon regardless of how many commas appear before or after:

```
=CONCAT(IF((RIGHT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($1:$40)-1)*99+1,99)))=",")*(RIGHT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1," ",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($1:$40)*99,99)))=":"),LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($1:$40)-1)*99+1,99)),LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($1:$40)-1)*99+1,99)))-1),""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

`CONCAT` was introduced in Office 365 Excel.

The formula adds a lot of extra spaces between the words then using mid we cycle through the words landing in that extra white space and trim each part.

We test whether the word ends in a comma and the next ends in a colon then returns the word minus the comma.

This has one flaw in that it will return every word that is followed by a comma where the next word ends in a colon.

[image]